# Compiler Error, Linked list: error: base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘IntNodeType’

Tags: c++, pointers

Below I have some basic code and I am learning about linked lists. This function passes an array and created a linked list from it. However, when I try to compile it I get an error about a non-pointer type. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks

```
struct IntNodeType {
   int value;
   IntNodeType * next;

   IntNodeType (int v=0, IntNodeType * p=NULL):value(v),next(p)
   {

   }
};
IntNodeType *  InitList (int a[], int size)
{
        IntNodeType *p;

        p = new IntNodeType[size];
        int i = 0;

        while ( i < size )
        {
                p[i]->value = a[i];

                if ( i == size - 1)
                {
                        p[i] -> next = NULL;
                        break;
                }
                else
                        p[i] -> next = p[i+1];

                i++;
        }

        return p;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To correctly compile your code, InitList's body should be:

```
    // ..
    IntNodeType *p;

    p = new IntNodeType[size];
    int i = 0;

    while ( i < size )
    {
            p[i].value = a[i]; // here

            if ( i == size - 1)
            {
                    p[i].next = nullptr; // here + nullptr
                    break;
            }
            else
                    p[i].next = &(p[i+1]); //here

            i++;
    }

    return p;
```

Notice the usage of the period operator instead of the `->` operator.

Although `p` is an array type (can be decayed into a pointer), its contents aren't pointers. `p` contains `size` many `IntNodeType`s.
For the last noted line you need to pass it a reference to the non-pointer `p[i+1]`

It's also worth noting you should use `nullptr` over `NULL`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your clear and thoughtful answer. I was just wondering under what conditions should I be using nullptr over null?

Comment: @chynna-hernandez In short, always. `nullptr` is the standard, `NULL` only causes issues. Please mark this as the solution if this has helped you, thanks!

Comment: I was trying to mark it, apparently there is a time limit as to when you can mark solutions, but I wanted to let you know that I did appreciate your help!